# Embed VCL form in FMX form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder, vcl

The main program we are working on is completly designed with the VCL, quite large and partly about 20 years old. In the next version it shall get a more modern UI under consideration of UWP guidelines and touch control.

Since we already started with app developement, we thought about building a general framework with FMX which can be used on different platforms. In the Windows version we want to integrate most of the VCL Forms, because reimplementing them all is not worthwile for us. Also the Windows version will have quite more functionality and support for our older products. So we only want to redesign those parts of the app, which also shall be part of the mobile version.

First we thought about splitting the app into two seperate executables for Windows. But in our new UI design we don't want to use modal dialogs.
So we would like to use a FMX container into which VCL Forms could be embedded.

**What I've done**

In my project, I have created a FMX multi-device app with a main Form and a DLL which contains a VCL form. The DLL exports functions to create and destroy the VCL Form, and a function which returns the handle of the created VCL Form.

In the main Form of the FMX app, the DLL is loaded and the VCL form is created. After getting the handle of the VCL Form, it is embedded into the main Form by calling the `SetParent()` function of the Win32 API:

```cpp
HWND vclFormHandle = GetVclFormHandleFromDll();
HWND fmxFormHandle = WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle)->Wnd;
SetParent(vclFormHandle, fmxFormHandle);
```

**Questions**

1. The embedded VCL Form can be controlled with the mouse. Also, editing text with the keyboard is possible. But switching between controls via the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, or executing a Button click via the <kbd>Return</kbd> key, doesn't work. To get this working in the VCL Form, I added a hook like this:

   ```cpp
   HHOOK hKeyBoardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyBoardProc, HInstance, NULL);

   RESULT CALLBACK KeyBoardProc (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
       // key event -> vcl controls       
       return CallNextHookEx(hKeyBoardHoof, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   }
   ```

   Before digging deeper into this, I wanted to ask if someone has a better idea to get those key events forwarded? (When setting a VCL Form as a parent, using the same mechanisms, it works fine without doing extra stuff).
2. I know that mixing VCL and FMX is not recommended by Embarcadero, but it seems as the described design could work. Can anyone see dangers or pitfalls in doing this?

Comment: This sounds pretty brittle and flaky to me. Surely you are better doing this properly and having bespoke UI for each platform.

Comment: Embarcadero's C++ product manager published a library to host FMX within a VCL app, but this probably does not help you as you're going the opposite direction (https://github.com/vintagedave/firemonkey-container)

Comment: FMX doesn't really have the infrastructure in place to support a VCL form.  For instance, it is missing a message loop that is capable of dispatching VCL internal messages, forwarding notifications from Parent to Child, etc since FMX doesn't use HWNDs for its controls, other than the top-level Form window.

Comment: I feel you're going down a rabbit hole here. You'll only be faced with more and more problems. If the real problem is that development is more comfortably done in VCL, then the solution is to start getting used to FMX. I'm interested to know the real reason why you want to keep VCL. I'm also finding it hard to understand how this should work based on your "and other platforms" in the first sentence. Anything compiled in VCL (including DLLs) just simply can't be used on another platform.

Comment: Thank you for your assesments. I tried to explain our situation more clearly, especially why we want to keep VCL. Based on your comments and my attempts to get this working, it seems that we should keep the UIs separated. Otherwise we will have an fragile Windows app with non standard behaviour. Providing DLLs with VCL Forms, which are only shown but not embedded, should work I think, but this propably won't meet our requirements.